# Alias for "| foreach { "$_" }" in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, pipeline

I like to use the following code to emulate the Unix "find" behavior:

```
ls DIRECTORY -recurse -include PATTERN | foreach { "$_" }
```

In fact, there are a couple of other commands that I'd like to append this `| foreach { "$_" }` to.  So I'm trying to find a way to make this easier to type.  I tried stuff like this:

```
function xfind {
    ls $args | foreach { "$_" }
}
```

And then I invoked it like so:

```
xfind DIRECTORY -recurse -include PATTERN
```

But that seemed to do the wrong thing...

Comment: A micro optimization for less typing would be to use the % instead of the foreach keyword.

Comment: Unless you have more than one pattern to search for (like *.cpp,*.h) use the `-filter` parameter instead of include to improve performance.  It might not matter on small dirs but can start to make a difference on big dirs and certainly on network shares.

Comment: It's very interesting how different PowerShell is from Unix shells.  Much less dynamic.  I have a (bash) function like this:
`le () { "$@" | less; }`
This function can run any command and pipe it thru less.  But I think this type of thing is not possible in PowerShell, if I look at Shay's answer.

Comment: @hibbelig you could do that in PowerShell if you really wanted to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider simply to use the `-name` switch of the `Get-ChildItem` (aka `ls`, `dir`):

```
ls DIRECTORY -recurse -include PATTERN -name
```

This way is native, clean, and effective.

Comment: Yes, this is really effective -- KISS!  I think I'll be using this.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it can be extended to a full blown advanced function. The key is to pass the parameters to ls by passing all of them using a special variable (PSBoundParameters) which is avaialble in advanced functions:

```
function xfind {

    [cmdletbinding()]

    param(
        [string[]]$path,
        [switch]$recurse,
        [string[]]$include
    )

    ls @PSBoundParameters | foreach { "$_" }   
}
```

Comment: This looks like the arguments in `param(...)` are replicating the signature of the `ls` cmdlet, so that it is not possible to write a generic "append foreach" function...  Is that actually the case?

Comment: Thank you very much for the response.  It answers precisely the question I asked.  Hope you don't mind that I still selected the other answer, for I wasn't aware of the `-Name` switch, and it is so attractive that I just _have_ to use it.

Comment: By "writing a generic 'append foreach' function" I meant to write a single function `xfoo` so that `xfoo bla bla` equals `bla bla | foreach { "$_" } `, no matter what exactly `bla bla` is.  But since your implementation of `xfind` enumerates its three parameters, it doesn't look like I could write something that doesn't depend on the parameters.